# Checking if there is more than one SUBstring occuring in a list, without explicitly defining the substring

Tags: python, string, list, search

I have a list of logs I want to analyze. I've got these logs into a list in Python. I want to check to make sure the following substring 'pattern' does not occur more than two times:

```
'Processing id xxxxxx'
```

Where xxxxxx is a specific ID. Basically, I do not want the logs to be processing the **same ID** more than twice... It can process several different ids, but if the **same ID** is processing over and over again, I want to know. I **do not know what the ID will be**, I just know I don't want the same one to be re-processed.

I understand how to check if a substring occurs more than once, but I do not know how to check for an id that I won't exactly know at the time.

```
# response is the list of logs that I am analyzing.
# substring is the 'Processing id xxxxxx' string.

process_str = [s for s in response if substring in s]
if len(process_str) > 2:
   ## raise a flag here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through logs to get the processing id and store them in a dictionary with the value being the number of times it occurs.

```
ids = {}
for s in response:
    m = re.search(r'(Processing id )(\d{6})', s)
    id = m.group(2)
    
    if id not in ids:
        ids[id] = 1
    else:
        ids[id] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if this works with IDs of any length? Some of my IDs have a length of 7 digits, while others can be 6 or 5.

Comment: Just change \d{6} to \d+ and it'll work with any length